# How can I set the assembly and file versions based on the date of compilation?

Tags: .net, vb.net, version, versioning

Is there any method to set those two versions to the current date and time automatically during the compilation? I would like it to set them like {YYYY}.{MM}.{DD}.{HHmm}; the last one could be the revision since there could be more than one compilation (bug fixes) per day.

[image: Example of what I would like to achieve]

Comment: When you find a way, I suggest using {YYYY}.{MM}.{DD}.{HHmm} otherwise version 1 will be a later version than version 2... sometimes.

Comment: You made a good point, I'm going to edit the question using that format.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://www.lionhack.com/2014/02/13/msbuild-override-assembly-version/. It's not exactly the solution you asked for, but has the bits you need to customise for your own needs